# Android Studio: How to resize an image before uploading to server?

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

I have an app that takes a picture, assigns it to an imageview and then uploads it to a parse server. 
The problem is that I need the images to be 200 x 200 px before upload. 
Is there a way to do this programatically?
this is my function so far:

```
 public void Myfunction (){


    //image
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos);
    byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("myimage.jpg",imageInByte);
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: By the way, you can obtain a FileOutputStream and compress directly to file, no need to use naps and imageInByte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To scale bitmap down before compress, add

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, false));
```

If your bitmap is not square, you probably want to crop it before scaling